# How to apply Normalisation using the MinMaxScaler() to all Columns, but Exclude the Categorical?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, machine-learning-model

Below, I have the following datatset:

`sample_df.head(2)`

```
ID     S_LENGTH     S_WIDTH     P_LENGTH     P_WIDTH     SPECIES
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1      3.5          2.5          5.6         1.7        VIRGINICA
2      4.5          5.6          3.4         8.7         SETOSA
```

Therefore, how to I apply normalisation to this dataset using the following code below to all my columns, excluding the `ID` and `SPECIES` columns?

I basically want to use the `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` to apply normalisation, so that all the features are in a range of 0 and 1.

This is the code I am using...

```
min_max = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
min_max.fit_transform(sample_df)
```

...but when I execute it, I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SETOSA'
```

Alternatively, if I do this...

```
min_max = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
min_max.fit_transform(sample_df[['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH']])

sample_df.head(2)
```

...I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sample'
```

Any help on how to accomplish what I want to do is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the result of `fit_transform`, you must assign to your columns.

```py
columns = ['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH', 'P_LENGTH', 'P_WIDTH']

min_max = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
df[columns] = min_max.fit_transform(df[columns])
df.head()
```

Output

```
   ID  S_LENGTH  S_WIDTH  P_LENGTH  P_WIDTH    SPECIES
0   1       0.0      0.0       1.0      0.0  VIRGINICA
1   2       1.0      1.0       0.0      1.0     SETOSA
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This has worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')  to exclude categorical columns.
Also while importing dataset, set the index_col='ID' to use ID as index instead of column.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I solve this error? ```AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sample'```

Comment: Please can you rerun your code from start? Because I can on myside.. I'm not getting this error

Comment: import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import datasets

data=datasets.load_iris()
Data=pd.DataFrame(data.data,columns=data.feature_names)
Data['Target']=data.target
Data.columns=['S_LENGTH','S_WIDTH','P_LENGTH','P_WIDTH','SPECIES']
sample_df=Data

min_max=MinMaxScaler()
min_max.fit_transform(sample_df[['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH']])
sample_df.head(2)

Comment: Thanks, but it still has the error.